# R2 in Lasso (vs. pearson correlation^2)

Tags: r, statistics, data-modeling, glmnet

I made a lasso model and want to get the R2 value.

```
library(glmnet)
lasso_sm <- model.matrix(mpg~., mtcars)
lasso_target <- mtcars[,"mpg"]
# Cross validation for regularization parameter
lasso_cv <- cv.glmnet(lasso_sm, lasso_target, alpha=1, nfolds=10)
plot(lasso_cv)
# Lasso 
lasso.mod <- glmnet(lasso_sm,lasso_target,alpha=1,lambda=lasso_cv$lambda.min)
```

I read that the R2 value is identical to the pearson correlation^2. From how I understood the manual, 
extracting the $dev.ratio of the glmnet object should return me the R2 value. However the results differ.

```
# R2
lasso.mod$dev.ratio
cor(y, rm_lasso_var_target)^2
```

Or is it better to show the MSE instead of R2 when „summarizing“ the lasso (This is what I concluded from different posts, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/estimating-r-squared-and-statistical-significance-from-penalized-regression-mode)?

Thanks for help!